# ItemsControl: Доступ из элемента к сведениям о родителе

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется следующая разметка:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="2.5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Padding="5"
                           Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           Padding="5"
                           Text="{Binding Weight}"/>

                <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="-1"
                           Fill="LightGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           Width="..."/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Здесь `Items` - некая коллекция элементов, упорядоченная по убыванию `Weight`. Что я хочу: подложить под `TextBlock'и` зеленый прямоугольник, но так, чтобы его ширина была пропорциональна значению `Weight`, причем за 100% принять большее значение (оно самое первое будет). Шаблон набросал, но что вписать в свойство `Width` никак не соображу. Тут надо, во-первых, учесть что эти 100% заведомо неизвестны, а во-вторых, что ширина `Grid` может быть любой.

Нарисовал что хочу получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В принципе можно набросать конвертер и передать в него параметром `Items`, но как учесть ширину тогда...

Comment: А если у rectangle сделать HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" и убрать задание Width?

Comment: @Gardes, тогда они все будут одинаковыми

Comment: не совсем понимаю что нужно, можете приложить скриншот того что получается и того что хотите?

Comment: А хороший вопрос, кстати. Если бы максимум был известен в VM, было бы куда проще.

Comment: @Gardes, нарисовал что хочу получить

Comment: @VladD, максимум по сути это `Items.First().Weight`, в принципе, если иначе никак - могу вынести в VM отдельно его

Comment: @Андрей: Проблема в том, что `MaxWeight` нужно обновлять, когда любой из `Weight`'ов изменится. Это можно сделать и в View, но будет достаточно много кода.

Comment: @VladD, элементы в `Items` неизменяемые (очень полезная штука из ФП, стараюсь применять по возможности), коллекция может измениться только полностью, поэтому это не проблема

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если максимальный вес есть отдельно в VM, то получается такой вот код:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="2.5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Padding="5"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Padding="5"
                   Text="{Binding Weight}"/>

                <ProgressBar Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="-1"
                   Background="Transparent" Foreground="LightGreen"
                   Value="{Binding Weight}" BorderThickness="0"
                   Maximum="{Binding DataContext.MaxWeight,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

На Windows 7 выглядит так:

[image: картинка]

Если хотите, чтобы стиль был один и тот же, проще всего таки приспособить прямоугольник. Для этого концептуально проще всего использовать конвертер.

Например, так. Ширина прямоугольника равна доступной ширине грида, умноженной на отношение `Weight` к `MaxWeight`. Оформляем это в виде конвертера.

```
class ProportionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type t, object p, CultureInfo ci) =>
        (double)values[0] / (double)values[1] * (double)values[2];

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] tt, object p, CultureInfo ci) =>
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

И оформляем такую разметку:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <local:ProportionConverter x:Key="ProportionConverter"/>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="2.5" Name="ContainerGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Padding="5"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Padding="5"
                   Text="{Binding Weight}"/>

                <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="-1"
                   Fill="LightGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Rectangle.Width>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ProportionConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Weight"/>
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.MaxWeight"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                         AncestorType=ItemsControl}"/>
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="ContainerGrid"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Rectangle.Width>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Результат:

[image: и ещё картинка]

---

Для эстетов, которые не хотят плодить конвертеры, можно извратиться, и реализовать деление при помощи двух трансформаций, причём одну из них нужно обратить. Вот так:

```
<Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="-1"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.5" x:Name="HelperGrid">
    <Grid.Tag>
        <ScaleTransform
            ScaleX="{Binding DataContext.MaxWeight,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
            ScaleY="1"/>
    </Grid.Tag>
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Weight}" ScaleY="1"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <Rectangle Fill="LightGreen" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0.5"
        RenderTransform="{Binding Tag.Inverse, ElementName=HelperGrid}"/>
</Grid>
```

Картинка получается та же.

Ещё один вариант, который [предложил в комментариях @Pavel Mayorov](/q/656282/656303#comment942296_656303):

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="-1">
    <Grid Width="{Binding DataContext.MaxWeight,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
          Height="1">
        <Rectangle Width="{Binding Weight}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Fill="LightGreen"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

(Я пробовал ещё варианты с `GradientBrush` и `RenderTransform` через конвертер, они тоже работают.)

Comment: Спасибо, хак с заменой на `ProgressBar` интересный, но есть минус - на разных ОС выглядит по разному, если на Win10 все плоско как и задумывалось, то на Win7 уже не то (на WinXP будут вообще прерывистые квадратики)

Comment: Ну уж вам не угодишь :) Сейчас сделаю.

Comment: @Андрей: Готово.

Comment: работает как надо, спасибо!

Comment: @Андрей: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Зачем так сложно с трансформациями? Можно просто взять Grid размера MaxWeight, а внутрь вложить прямоугольник размера Weight, после чего все вместе обернуть во Viewbox.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Круто, чё! Я не догадался.

Comment: @VladD ну, я не столько догадался, сколько нагляделся на XAML, который генерирует Inkspace :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, как ответ оформите?

Comment: @Андрей проверить не на чем

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Я проверил, работает :)

Comment: Да мне синтаксис проверить негде :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Добавил ваш вариант со ссылкой на комментарий. Если вы напишете отдельным ответом, я уберу.